# csv to JSON not working

Tags: javascript, php, json, csv

I have a csv file that I want transfer into JSON but it doesn't work the way I was hoping

PHP

```
$file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];    
$csv= file_get_contents($file);     
$array = array_map('str_getcsv', explode(";", $csv));
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('OK!');</script>";
```

---

javascript

```
var myJsarray = <?= json_encode($array); ?>;
alert(myJsarray[0][0]);
```

my csv looks something like this

```
aaa;46
bbb;23
ccc;51
ddd;23
```

and my output looks like this

```
[["aaa"],["46\r\nbbb"],["23\r\nccc"],["51\r\nddd"],["23"]];
```

and I was hoping to get

```
[["aaa"],["46"],["bbb"],["23"],["ccc"],["51"],["ddd"],["23"]]
```

my idea was to put `"$csv=explode("\n", $csv)"` under `"$csv= file_get_contents($file); "`
But it gave me error that "$csv is not a string.

Comment: `\r\n` suggests there are newlines after each separated value. These should be removed. Open your csv in notepad++ and see if there are new lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jdl-enterprises.co.uk/sof/25763045.php

If it's something like this that you want:

```
$csv= file_get_contents($file);

$array = explode("\r\n", $csv); // Update this to \n if need be or however you csv saves it

for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    $array[$i] = explode(';', $array[$i]);
}
```

This will produce:

```
[["aaa","46"],["bbb","23"],["ccc","51"],["ddd","23"]]
```

And if you want it like your example, add into the code:

```
$array2 = array();
foreach($array as $ar) {
    foreach($ar as $a) {
        $array2[] = $a;
    }
}
```

This will produce:

```
["aaa"],["46"],["bbb"],["23"],["ccc"],["51"],["ddd"],["23"]
```

Obviously there is a set of [ ] missing around the whole code, but you could stuff it all inside another array, or just add them manually.

Comment: noup..now i got  [["aaa","46\r\nbbb","23\r\nccc","51\r\nddd","23"]]

Comment: Sorry, your example had spaces initially, let me update the code. Updated the code. Should work now.

Comment: but when i add "\n" in first explode i got this [["aaa","46\r"],["bbb","23\r"],["ccc","51\r"],["ddd","23"]];
i need to see in my javascript function can I work with this

Comment: I meant to put \r\n, sorry about the confusion, my csv file is just a mock up of yours and only needed \n

Comment: jea jea that's good..i think i could work with that.. need to check

Answer (score 0):

Your "CSV" is in an incorrect format:

```
aaa;46 bbb;23 ccc;51 ddd;23
```

Change it to:

```
aaa,46 bbb,23 ccc,51 ddd,23
```

Comment: Think he's using semi-colons rather than commas, as long as that is set as the delimiter it shouldn't matter

Comment: my csv was maid in excel,when i open it in notepad i got this

Answer (score 0):

You do know there is a function just for reading CSV in PHP? It's called fgetcsv()

```
$data = array();
$fh = fopen('file.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ';')) !== false) {
    $data[] = $line;
}
fclose($fh);
echo json_encode($data);
```